# jQuery error box is not going while I clicked on it in first time. when i click again second time it is going

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery  error box is not going while I clicked on it in first time. when i click again second time in is going.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

jQuery.validator.addMethod("file", function( value, element ) {
                var ext = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                var result = this.optional(element) || ext == "csv" || ext == "CSV";
                return result;
        }, '<div class="errorbox rateError"><div class="error-message">* Please upload only csv file</div><div class="error-arrow"></div></div>');
var $Zone = $('#ZoneZone').attr('name');

var $params = {debug:false,rules:{},messages:{}};

$params['rules'][$Zone] = {"required": true};
$params['messages'][$Zone] = {"required":'<div class="errorbox rateError"><div class="error-message">* Please enter Zone</div><div class="error-arrow"></div></div>'
};

 $("#ZoneAdminAddForm").validate($params);

jQuery(document).on('click','.errorbox',function(){
        alert("click");
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });                                  
    });

});
```

When I clicked on errorbox first time nothing happening but when i clicked again second time its giving alert click and that error message is going.

I tried to give no conflict code as well but it is not working.

Same code is working in some other page.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: so, see Kevin Bowersox answer and use .on() delegation which is really better than live()

Comment: @roasted I checked But its showing same response.. I will update my full code pls see..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.on() is for jQuery version 1.7 and above. If you have an older version, use this:

```
$('.errorbox').live('click',function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $(this).remove();
        });                                  
    });


   $('.errorbox').live('focus', function()
    {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $(this).remove();        
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead of `live` and wrap the code in `document.ready`.  I suspect the dom elements are not loaded when this code first attempts to bind the event handler.  The `live` method has been deprecated for awhile and the `on` method is preferred, it uses event propogation to assign event handlers to elements currently not rendered on the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','.errorbox',function(){
        alert("click");
        $(this).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });                                  
    });
});
```

Comment: Same response when i clicked first time nothing again when I clicked second time it alerts and removing the error message

Comment: Do you execute some script on load of the page that adds the `.errorbox`?